# How to present a camera in complicated view hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS 10.3.1

I've got the following view controller hierarchy...

```
<TabBarController 0x1463d550>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x146434b0> not in the window
   | <TabMapController 0x146396f0>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x16168be0> not in the window
   |    | <ControlBar 0x1619ad60>, state: disappeared, view: <UIToolbar 0x161b6d40> not in the window
   |    | <ArcGisViewController 0x14d7a200>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x162cd2c0> not in the window
   |    | <iRpMainDashboardViewController 0x14dc1a00>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x16553d60> not in the window
   |    |    | <iRpImageFlipperViewController 0x16615910>, state: disappeared, view: <IGGridView 0x14dfec00> not in the window
   |    |    | <iRpImageFlipperViewController 0x165567e0>, state: disappeared, view: <IGGridView 0x14e31e00> not in the window
   + <UINavigationController 0x14a13800>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x16282410>, presented with: <_UIFullscreenPresentationController 0x16cad680>
   |    | <TabMobile 0x15a53400>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x162844a0>
   |    |    | <TabMobileDetail 0x16ca63c0>, state: appeared, view: <BaseView 0x162f4020>
   |    |    |    | <MobileAccount 0x16ca8440>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x16ca9030>
   |    |    |    |    | <ComboBoxController 0x16cd2510>, state: appeared, view: <ComboBoxView 0x16cce9a0>
   |    |    |    |    | <ComboBoxController 0x16cab940>, state: appeared, view: <ComboBoxView 0x16cd15c0>
   |    |    |    | <MobileCharacteristic 0x16cd2840>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x16cd2b60>
   |    |    |    |    | <ComboBoxController 0x16fb7630>, state: appeared, view: <ComboBoxView 0x16d05da0>
   |    |    |    |    | <ComboBoxController 0x16fb9300>, state: appeared, view: <ComboBoxView 0x16d05fc0>
   |    |    |    |    | <ComboBoxController 0x16fb77f0>, state: appeared, view: <ComboBoxView 0x16d060d0>
   |    |    |    |    | <ComboBoxController 0x16fb79b0>, state: appeared, view: <ComboBoxView 0x16d05eb0>
   |    |    |    | <MobileLocation 0x16fb7b70>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x16d1ca60>
   |    |    |    |    | <ComboBoxController 0x16d065c0>, state: appeared, view: <ComboBoxView 0x16d21530>
   |    |    |    |    | <ComboBoxController 0x16d2a2f0>, state: appeared, view: <ComboBoxView 0x16d21790>
   |    |    |    | <AxGridPictController 0x16d25b00>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x165b2730>
   |    |    | <GridControlBar 0x16aeeff0>, state: appeared, view: <GridControlBarView 0x16d3ddf0>
```

The AxGridPictController (see near the bottom of the hierarchy) has a camera button on it.

I have code within the AppDelegate that is trying to present the camera when the user taps the camera button on AxGridPictController.

I'm presenting the camera with this code in my AppDelegate...

```
-(void)presentCameraToUser
    {          
        //Create observer for notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performTask:) name:@"ImageCapture" object:nil];

        //open camera view controller
        self.cameraViewController = [[AVCamCameraViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AVCamCameraViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self.tabBarController presentViewController:self.cameraViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

I don't have a reference to my UINavigationController from AppDelegate, as the UINavigationController is presented from another class entirely.  My camera code is centralized to AppDelegate class so that any one of my classes can use the camera.

You'll note that my presentation code is `[self.tabBarController presentViewController... ]` but you'll also notice according to the view controller hierarchy, that once I present the navigation controller, the `tabBarController` has `state: disappeared` and `view: not in the window` so I'm assuming it's useless for me to try and use the `tabBarController` to present the camera.

Assuming I could even get a reference to the UINavigationController, I'm not even sure that the navigation controller is capable of presenting a full screen camera view.

Is what I'm trying to do... present a camera while a navigation controller is active... even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be amazingly simple. Instead of using a parent view controller to ***present*** the UINavigationController, I instead ***added*** it to the parent view like this...

```
-(void)addAChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController
    {
        [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
        [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
```

And instead of ***dismissing*** the UINavigationController, I just ***remove*** it with code like this...

```
-(void)removeThisViewControllerFromItsParent
    {
        [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self removeFromParentViewController];
    }
```